# i want to UPDATE table from COUNT of another table fields in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 table

structure are:-

student_attendance table

```
|scholar_no|att_date   |att_status|
 101        01/07/2021    P
 102        01/07/2021    P
 101        02/07/2021    P
 102        02/07/2021    A
 ......
 .....
 101        01/08/2022    P
 102        01/08/2022    P
```

student_yearly_info table

```
|education_year|scholar_no|total_present|
Jul 21          101        28
Jul 21          102        29
```

I want table 2 `monthly_att` field `total_present` update with first table attendees  field `att_status`.
my query always 0 row return:-

```
$sql=$conn->prepare( "UPDATE `student_yearly_info` AS Y 
                        LEFT JOIN student_attendance AS A ON A.scholar_no=Y.scholar_no 
                        SET Y.end_Year=?,           
                            Y.total_present=count(A.att_status)  
                      WHERE Y.education_year LIKE ? ");
```

pls Help me

Comment: You need to do a select and the JOIN after the update clause.

Comment: thanks  JoelCrypto but
when use select with update query. Performance speed very slow. any other method without select statement?

Comment: Do you have indexes? Btw I don’t have the whole data structure to help.

Comment: Table structure for table `student_yearly_info`

CREATE TABLE `student_yearly_info` (
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_dise` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `education_year` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `end_Year` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scholar_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `currunt_class` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `currunt_class_section` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `total_present` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_Days` int(11) NOT NULL
) 
 Indexes for table `student_yearly_info`
PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`);

Comment: CREATE TABLE `student_attendance` (
  `student_att_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_dise` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `scholar_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `att_date` date NOT NULL,
  `att_time` time NOT NULL,
  `att_status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
)PRIMARY KEY (`student_att_id`);

Comment: this is my table structure.